# Chrome Jquery date picker null error in debug

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery date picker and when I run the code below. The calendar will not pop up and I get this error in the debug. What shocks me most is that I wrapped my method in the $(document).ready so idk how it's null.

MyPage.aspx:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'datepicker' of null
    at HTMLDocument. (MyPage.aspx:47)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

Here is my Code

```
  <%--Calendar Code--%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

           var sixMonthLimit = new Date();
           sixMonthLimit.setMonth(sixMonthLimit.getMonth() - 6);

           $("#<%= StartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker(
           {
               minDate: sixMonthLimit,
               maxDate: new Date(),
               changeMonth: true,
               numberOfMonths: 1,
               onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                   $("#<%= EndDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
               }
           });

           $("#<%= EndDate.ClientID %>").datepicker(
           {
               maxDate: new Date(),
               changeMonth: true,
               numberOfMonths: 1,
               onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                   $("#<%= StartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
               }
           });
       });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery never returns `null` from `$("selector")`, even if the element isn't found. I suspect you've loaded something that redefined `$` so it's not jQuery any more. You can put a parameter into the `document.ready()` function to make sure it's available with this name locally.

```
    $(document).ready(function ($) { // $ here binds the name in this scope

       var sixMonthLimit = new Date();
       sixMonthLimit.setMonth(sixMonthLimit.getMonth() - 6);

       $("#<%= StartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker(
       {
           minDate: sixMonthLimit,
           maxDate: new Date(),
           changeMonth: true,
           numberOfMonths: 1,
           onClose: function (selectedDate) {
               $("#<%= EndDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
           }
       });

       $("#<%= EndDate.ClientID %>").datepicker(
       {
           maxDate: new Date(),
           changeMonth: true,
           numberOfMonths: 1,
           onClose: function (selectedDate) {
               $("#<%= StartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
           }
       });
   });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to using JQuery and this is so helpful.